# Having rows with different number of columns in Flex Datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, adobe

I am trying to understand if having different number of columns for different rows in a flex data grid is possible. For example, in Microsoft excel, you can select multiple columns and then merge them without effecting other rows that you did not select. Is something like that possible in flex data grids?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the point of datagrids, is to show a set of data of the same kind ... so no, this will not work ...

you should have a look at [flex-table](http://code.google.com/p/flex-table/), it's quite what you are looking for i think ...